# Changing XML's Layout Styles within Java / Adding Variables to XML

Tags: android

I have an app currently on the market and a few users have asked if they could change the layout background colours. EG at the moment I have black background with white text and they would like it to be white background with black text.

I would like to add it as a App Settings so the users can decide themselves. Is There a way to add a variable within the XML so when the layout is called it checks to see which colours to use?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the below [link](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html)

you can achieve so and so by applying themes to your application.